# Android Dialogs and Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I am bit confused that, is dialog an activity or not? if yes can we perform operation as we do on activity and set custom layout that can be loaded from XML..

Answer (score 0):

Dialog is part of an Activity and yes you can assign custom XML layout to a Dialog.

You can visit here for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is an Activity which has its own layout and class. You can see the example below, and understand how all these used together and the connections.

[How to create Dialog Activity](http://www.javabeat.net/dialog-activity-android/)

Answer (score 0):

yes dialog is same as activity.. It loads its layout from XML layout file and all operations